# Jenkins pass trigger block to Shared Library Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a Shared Library containing a declarative pipeline which numerous jobs are using to build with.
However I want to be able to pass the trigger block in from the Jenkinsfile to the Shared Library as some jobs I want to trigger via Cron, others I want to trigger via SNS and others with an upstream job trigger.

Is there a way I can do this? Everything I have tried so fails

I have tried

```
#Jenkinsfile
@Library('build') _
buildAmi{
OS = "amazonlinux"
owners = "amazon"
filters = "\"Name=name,Values=amzn-ami-hvm-*-x86_64-gp2\""
template = "linux_build_template.json"
trigger = triggers {
    cron('0 H(06-07) * * *')
}

#Shared Lib
pipeline {
    $buildArgs.trigger
```

which fails with

```
Not a valid section definition
```

Have also tried passing just the cron schedule into the Shared lib e.g.

```
triggers {
    cron("${buildArgs.cron}")
}
```

but that gives the error

```
Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks
```

Have tried various other thing but it seems the declarative style requires a trigger block with just triggers inside.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Does that trigger block give anything special ?  you can easily pass the cron constructor requirement as string and instantiate the correct desired trigger. https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/312fcd1b9ebb5f4ce396c2b7cc93659edd6301c1/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/Trigger.java

Comment: The trigger block is the declarative way for defining triggers. If I created a Cron object how would I get Jenkins to respect that as a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Too much code for a comment:

We wanted to merge some preset properties with jenkinsfile properties.
This is the way to get this to work since the properties method can only be called once.

We used an additional pipeline parameter with the trigger info:

Jenkinsfile:

```
mypipeline (
    pipelineTriggers:   [pollSCM(scmpoll_spec: '0 5,11,15,22 * * 1-5')],
)
```

then in the shared library

```
@Field def pipelineProperties = [
    disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true),
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10', artifactNumToKeepStr: '0'))
]
def pipelineTriggersArgs = args.pipelineTriggers
def setJobProperties() {
    def props = pipelineProperties
    def str = ""
    pipelineProperties.each { str += (blue + it.getClass().toString() + it.toString() + "\n") }
    if (pipelineTriggersArgs) {
        if (debugLevel > 29) {
            def plTrig = pipelineTriggers(pipelineTriggersArgs)
            str += (mag + "args: " + pipelineTriggersArgs.getClass().toString() + "\t\t" + pipelineTriggersArgs.toString() + "\n" + off)
            str += (red + "expr: " + plTrig.getClass().toString() + "\t\t" + plTrig.toString() + "\n" + off)
            echo str
        }
        props?.add(pipelineTriggers(pipelineTriggersArgs))      // pass param with list as the arg
    }
    properties(props)
}
```

That was the only way to merge preset and parameters since the properties cannot be overwritten. not exactly the answer but an approach to solve it I think.